# SSRS Conditionally remove rows from a table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, properties, rows, ssrs-tablix

[image]

---

[image: Preview Mode as is now]

---

I am new to SSRS and need to get this working for my project(work not school)

I have implemented the data to be hidden on expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Offset1.Value = "",true,false)
```

Problem is that It leaves the empty space where those values would have been in my Report.  I need the space to disappear too.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am getting my data from a MS Access DB (if that matters)

Comment: Are you trying to hide an entire row or column?  I think a screenshot would be helpful in this case.

Comment: @Eric Screenshots added as per request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much head scratching and thinking about it differently.  @django made me think visibility not hidden properties.  I righ clicked the row header tab and clicked on the Row Visability... option.  That brings up the Change display options dialog box.  I selected the Show or hide based on an expression andthen the fx button to build the expression.  The expression i used was

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Offset1.value),true,false)
```

clicked OK

Ran Preview and this is what i got as a result:
[image: Finished Product!!]

Comment: That works too.  I forgot about that one to be honest but yes you can set visibility on rows AND columns too. In SSRS as in most development there are many ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I agree... Sometimes it just taking a step back and thinking about what you want in a different way that will actually get you where you intend on going!!  Dont be afraid to +1 if this helps anyone else either!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you need a 'visibility' on a grouping more than a hidden expression and you can use ISNOTHING() instead of = "".  I believe (not sure don't quote me ;) ) that SSRS evaluates hidden to only hide values not the object container itself(the row).  You may be better with your group or 'details' group to have an evaluative expression on the 'visibility' rather than an element you used instead.  Let's give a very simple example to drive home the concept:

1. Create a simple dataset in a new report.  DataSource does not matter as this is only a table variable that is self contained.

   ```
   declare @Temp table ( Code char(1), Value int)
   insert into @Temp values ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('A',null);

   select * from @Temp
   ```
2. Create a table from the toolbox and populate both columns with the data from your set.
3. Copy and paste this table right below itself in the report.
4. Now for the second report click anywhere inside it but in the lower left you should see 'Row Groups' in the 'Design' view of Business Intelligence Development Studio (or the web creator if you are using that).  Right Click '=(Details1)' (or similar) and choose 'Group Properties.
5. Now select 'Visibilty' on the left pane.  This relate to the entire grouping, not just a cell in an element.  Hit the 'Fx' under 'Show or hide based on an expression'.
6. Enter in the expression:

   ```
   =IIF( ISNOTHING(Fields!Value.Value)  , true, false)
   ```
7. Preview the report.  You should see the first table with three rows and the second table IGNORES the third row because it qualifies as nothing which it evaluates for the ENTIRE GROUPING to mean 'do not show'.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you are wanting me to do... Should I create a completely new report for the sake of a temp table?  If so is it different to do so with an Access DB?  I tried following your steps and it doesn't parse the code declare (at symbol)Temp...etc.

Comment: I like the ISNOTHING()  Tried and works but still having issues with the row data being hidden but not the space it would have required

Comment: Marked as Answer for helping me think about it in a different way than I was to come up with correct answer... THANK YOU @django

Comment: Mine was just an example for you in a new report but it looks like you got what you needed.